# Protobuf: Protocol message was modified concurrently during serialization

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Task flow was running in single thread, a core dump is still triggered.

Full log message with context:

```
Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
#0  0x00007f871bb011f7 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-196.el7.x86_64 keyutils-libs-1.5.8-3.el7.x86_64 krb5-libs-1.15.1-51.el7_9.x86_64 libcom_err-1.42.9-19.el7.x86_64 libgcc-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64 libgomp-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64 libselinux-2.5-15.el7.x86_64 libstdc++-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64 openssl-libs-1.0.2k-22.el7_9.x86_64 pcre-8.32-17.el7.x86_64 zlib-1.2.7-19.el7_9.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f871bb011f7 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f871bb028e8 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f871c5e8935 in google::DumpStackTraceAndExit () at src/utilities.cc:159
#3  0x00007f871c5def9d in google::LogMessage::Fail () at src/logging.cc:1685
#4  0x00007f871c5e1c97 in google::LogMessage::SendToLog (this=0x7f820942b3a0) at src/logging.cc:1642
#5  0x00007f871c5deb33 in google::LogMessage::Flush (this=this@entry=0x7f820942b3a0) at src/logging.cc:1509
#6  0x00007f871c5e052e in google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal (this=0x7f820942b3a0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at src/logging.cc:2256
#7  0x000000000145f8b3 in brpc::BaiduStreamingLogHandler (level=<optimized out>, filename=0x1a62e20 "google/protobuf/message_lite.cc", line=75,
    message="CHECK failed: (byte_size_before_serialization) == (byte_size_after_serialization): fs.interface.FsResponse was modified concurrently during serialization.")
    at src/brpc/global.cpp:308
#8  0x00000000015ed651 in google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::Finish (this=0x7f820942b440) at google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:254
#9  0x00000000015edad8 in google::protobuf::internal::LogFinisher::operator= (this=this@entry=0x7f820942b42f, other=...) at google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:267
#10 0x00000000015ff509 in google::protobuf::(anonymous namespace)::ByteSizeConsistencyError (byte_size_before_serialization=byte_size_before_serialization@entry=1706832,
    byte_size_after_serialization=<optimized out>, bytes_produced_by_serialization=bytes_produced_by_serialization@entry=1706862, message=...) at google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:75
#11 0x00000000015fff1f in google::protobuf::MessageLite::SerializePartialToArray (this=0x7f8387d1c048, data=0x7f7f81bbbe00, size=size@entry=1706832) at google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:488
```

How to avoid to the core dump?

Comment: Show us the serialization code

Answer (score 0):

The key here is

```
ByteSizeConsistencyError 
(byte_size_before_serialization=byte_size_before_serialization@entry=1706832,
 byte_size_after_serialization=, 
 bytes_produced_by_serialization=bytes_produced_by_serialization@entry=1706862
```

The protobuf library computes the size of messages prior to serializing them. The error can be caused by either the message being modified by another thread or a mistake in the computation. If you only access the object from a single thread, the cause is likely the latter one. This would typically be a bug in the protobuf library code, though it could also be e.g. memory corruption due to a mistake in your own code.

Here are some search results that have the same error message:

- Bug in protobuf library for `MapEntry` type: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/7399
- Wrong compiler optimization settings for CPU: https://protobuf.narkive.com/IFx5L90b/error-byte-size-calculation-and-serialization-were-inconsistent
- Access to uninitialized memory: https://www.mail-archive.com/protobuf@googlegroups.com/msg07385.html

Your problem could be similar to one of those, or something completely different. It can be quite difficult to resolve. The first step would be to remove parts of your code until you have a minimal example that reproduces the problem. After you have minimized the complete code to less than 100 lines, it gets much easier for other people to take a look and help.